# Extract values from particular JSON array

Tags: php, json, ajax

Given the following example JSON:

```
{
   "results":{
      "first":[
         true,
         "Matthew"
      ],
      "second":[
         false,
         "Unapplied"
      ],
      "third":[
         false,
         "Invalid Code"
      ]
   },
   "unused":728
}
```

as response from the following ajax call:

```
    var code = 'RDMPT21';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'codecheck.php',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {"redeem":code},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

How could I grab the first and the second values of each key and display them in the log console? I tried to use `console.log(data[first])` in the success function as well, but I get `undefined`, why?

Comment: Because the first level of your object only contains the keys `results` and `unused`.

Comment: `data["results"].first`(or `data.results.first`) throws the `error: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined` as well.

Comment: Sorry, I mispelled it, the outcome is the same, that's why I'm struggling to find a solution. The weird thing is that if I type data[1], I get the " symbol in return, like if the array is somehow broken and split by every single character, any idea about why this would happen?

Comment: That would likely mean, that your data is still a _string_ value, and that parsing the JSON into a JS data structure did not actually happen. `dataType: 'json'` _should_ make jQuery parse it automatically, before it gets passed to the callback function, not sure why that did not happen here. Any errors/warnings in the console?

Comment: That's where I'm probably lost. No errors in the console, and the php just does an `echo json_encode($result);` at the very end of the function, so it should be already in JSON format, but after 4 hours struggling with this I was hoping for a solution here on SO. Thanks for your kind anwers, I hope we can find a solution!

Comment: Well you could just remove the `dataType` argument, and do `data = JSON.parse(data)` first in your callback function.

Comment: Same outcome unfortunately.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what exactly `console.log(data)` (without trying to parse it first), and then `console.log(JSON.parse(data))` result in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230588/discussion-between-v3ntus-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error appeared to be coming from the JSON itself, which was formatted as Object instead, so I was able to grab the desired values by using:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

to later be able to grab my value needed with:

```
console.log(data["results"]["first"][0]);
console.log(data["results"]["first"][1]);
```

Special thanks to CBroe for the heads up.